# Getting Elements of a Char** from an address

Tags: c++, c, kernel, nachos

I'm working on Kernel programming (Nachos), and having some trouble passing an array of arguments from a userprogram into kernel land. Similar to argc, argv in C, C++, the user program passes:

```
char *args
```

into a syscall. In the kernel, I only get an address of where args is located. Now, my thoughts here are that I can cast this int to a char*, and then access the array via subscript, as in the user program. But this gives me cannot access memory errors.

Any thoughts?

I've tried accessing args a few ways, they are shown here:

```
char *argv = (char *) ReadRegister() // ReadRegister returns an int, addr of args
```

in addition to

```
char **argv = (char **) ReadRegister()
```

I have then tried getting each argument via either

```
argv[i]
```

or

```
&argv[i]
```

Both give Memory access errors.

Comment: Are you expecting simply an array of characters? Or are you expecting an array of strings?

Comment: Strings. Same as argv in c, c++

Comment: What you have right there is a pointer to a char, therefore you will only get an array of chars not strings. I suppose you wanted char**?

Comment: Yeah, i thought that same thing. But I get that same Cannot access Memory at address... error either way I use it.

Comment: Could you show how you're accessing args?

Comment: Try `char **argv = (char **) ReadRegister()`

Comment: My fault, typo in what I added. I tried that one

Comment: how do you know that the address provided is a good address and within your address space?

Comment: This article provides [a note about using readVirtualMemory function](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/courses/cs162-F05/Nachos/walk/x416.html) and others to transfer data from user space to kernel space.

Comment: If you are getting pointers from userland, and accessing in kernel, you should probably use `copyin()`, or `copyinstr()`, before you try to access the data. At least most Unix variants have memory boundary between user and kernel, memory space. But I don't know what Nachos is specifically.